# adding elements in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, scorm

how do i add an element to my attrib ?
i know how to add with text:

```
ET.subElement(root[2],'resource')
for x in root.iter('resource'):
```

but what i'm looking for is:

```
<resources>
        <resource identifier="presentation_3" type="webcontent" href="questions.html" adlcp:scormtype="sco">
            <file href="questions.html"/>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

below is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = "imsmanifest.xml"

tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

ET.SubElement(root[2],'file').set('href','index.html')
tree.write('new.xml')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I presume that you want to add the `file` element as a child of the `resource` element. Please be very clear about what the input is and what the expected output is. Note that `adlcp:` in `adlcp:scormtype` is interpreted as a namespace prefix that needs to be declared; otherwise the document cannot be parsed as XML.

Comment: thank you, i am learning alot! sorry my explaination wasn't, clear i want to add a child element under resources `<resource identifier="presentation_3" type="webcontent" href="questions.html" adlcp:scormtype="sco"></resource>` and i was wondering why my copied xml file does not contain 'adlcp' but how do i declare it on python ?

Comment: What do you mean by "my copied xml file"? Edit the question to clarify the problem.